# Fedora 32 monitor not detected

Tags: linux, fedora

just starting using a fresh install of Fedora 32 and getting to learn Linux on a new Dell Latitude 5510 laptop but my external monitor is not detected(connected with HDMI, also tried with Diplayport over USB Type-C), planning to use two monitors. I have Intel® UHD Graphics 620,
using `Xfce` and kernel 5.8.10-200.fc32.x86_64, also tried 5.6 kernel.

`inxi -G` returns

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: N/A 
  Device-2: Realtek Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: Fedora Project X.org 1.20.8 driver: vesa 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.1 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.1.8
```

`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display` returns

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Dell Device 09a1
    Kernel modules: i915
```

**UPDATE:result from `xandr`**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

**UPDATE:result from `dmesg | egrep -i "i915|firmware"`**

```
[    0.301664] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.460998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.461012] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.462306] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.462510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 50.3e391d3e.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.463904] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    3.666544] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    5.211818] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    5.212250] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1710707 usecs
[    5.231258] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
[   66.780884] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

**result from `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`**

```
You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly
Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
usb: port power management may be unreliable
i8042: Warning: Keylock active
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03: WQBC data block query control method not found
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: i2c-DELL09A1:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: i2c-DELL09A1:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
acpi PNP0C14:07: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Accelerometer lis3lv02d is present on SMBus but its address is unknown, skipping registration
uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Realtek Extended Controls Unit was not initialized!
uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 7 was not initialized!
uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
uvcvideo 1-6:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
```

Is there an issue with the driver? Am i missing something or is there anything else i can check?

Comment: To help gather more info, 1) when you connect the external monitor to HDMI, at that instant what do you see on external monitor? Expecting: Some kind of default complaint about `No Source` for example. 2) While HDMI connected run `xrandr` and update the question with this info. 3) Connect external monitor via Displayport over USB-C, what's shown on the external monitor? 4) Run `xrandr` and is it different? If different then include in answer, otherwise no need.

Comment: Updated the question,I get No signal from both sources.

Comment: I also see in Settings-Display is set on 77 Hz refresh rate, although my monitors are 60 Hz.

Comment: The X11 server seems to be running on the `vesa` driver instead of `modesetting`, so the display is accessed in a legacy way with no acceleration and reduced feature set. Perhaps your system is missing the Intel iGPU firmware? Do you have the `linux-firmware-20200316-106` package installed?

Comment: Please also post the output of `dmesg | egrep -i "i915|firmware"` and `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` for good measure.

Comment: Updated the output from `dmesg`.I don't see the package `linux-firmware-20200316-106` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons you're booting with the `nomodeset` parameter as indicated by your `dmesg` output:

*You have booted with nomodeset*

This parameter basically disables your Intel iGPU driver and boots you into VESA which is just wrong. I've no idea how and why but you must remove this option from your boot loader configuration.

Please check you don't have it in either of these files:

- `/etc/default/grub`
- `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`
- `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grubenv`

Or simply press <kbd>e</kbd> once you see the GRUB2 boot prompt and check this parameter is not specified.

Comment: Made the changes and all is working smoothly.Many thanks for you help.One more question, I am still seeing `iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2`. Is there an issue here also?I have AX201 network card, but `inxi` displays AC 9462.

Comment: If your WiFi adapter works this file is not necessary. Intel has yet to release it.